# NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_true'

Tags: ruby, assertions, testunit

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_true'
```

Am getting above error while running tests using test-unit in ruby. test-unit gem and rake versions are below,

```
test-unit (2.5.5)
rake (10.1.0)
```

Sample test file:-

```
require 'test/unit'

class Sample < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    # code block
  end

  def test_sample
    assert_true("test"=="test")
  end

  def teardown
    # code block
  end

end
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: Do you have a minimal example we can have a look at?

Comment: It looks like `require 'test/unit'` is actually loading the `test/unit` library from the standard library, not the `test/unit` library from the `test-unit` gem. Can you confirm that the gem is actually installed for the version of Ruby you are running your tests in and that it is in fact on the `$LOAD_PATH`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think you are right. assert_true is working in my local not in server. How to resolve this issue. i donn't know how to check loadpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by using following way. No need to change assert statements.

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'

class Sample < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    # code block
  end

  def test_sample
    assert_true("test"=="test")
  end

  def teardown
    # code block
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

`assert_true` does not appear to be in the list of available assertions for test-unit. Try using `assert`. Reference: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html

Comment: Then assert_true is listed here http://rubydoc.info/github/test-unit/test-unit/Test/Unit/Assertions:assert_true. How ?

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.9.2, test/unit is a wrapper around minitest, implemented [directly in the ruby source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/lib/test/unit/assertions.rb). The `assert_true` method does not exist in the new implementation, just use `assert` instead, as Simon Brahan already suggested. So the gem source you were looking at is no longer in use. The now relevant documentation is [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html).